# Get the cell value to SAP field

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I have five VBA projects that work, using the same syntax as I used on this one, but this does not.

I need to input data from my sheet to some fields at the F-63 transaction.

Another problem is that the code does not stop even if the cell has "OK" on it.

```vb
Sub f63()
    Dim cell, rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & Sheet1.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)

    If Not IsObject(Applicatio) Then
        Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
        Set Applicatio = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    End If
    If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
        Set Connection = Applicatio.Children(0)
    End If
    If Not IsObject(session) Then
       Set session = Connection.Children(0)
    End If
    If IsObject(WScript) Then
       WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
       WScript.ConnectObject Applicatio, "on"
    End If
    session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    
    For Each cell In rng

        If Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value <> "OK" Then

            session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
            session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nf-63"
            session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBKPF-BLDAT").Text = Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtBKPF-XBLNR").Text = Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtBKPF-BKTXT").Text = Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRF05V-NEWKO").Text = Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRF05V-NEWKO").SetFocus
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRF05V-NEWKO").caretPosition = 10
            session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
            
            Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value = "OK"
            
         End If
    
    Next cell

    MsgBox "Concluído", vbInformation, "F-63"
```

Comment: I define the range right after the sub name as above: 
Sub f63()
    Dim cell, rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & Sheet1.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)

Answer (score 0):

Note : When you referee to a Range of cells the first cell of the range is always row number 1. So if you change your range in your code, it will work on different areas on the same sheet. Your cell is where it reads, and Cells is the active sheet. Better if you remove the Range stuff here, and only referee to active sheet as `Cells(row, colums)` are. And use the column number in stead. Like this:

```
i = 1
Do Until Cells(i, 1) = ""
If Cells(i, 5).Value <> "OK" Then

      session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nf-63"
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBKPF-BLDAT").Text = Cells(i, 2).Value
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtBKPF-XBLNR").Text = Cells(i, 1).Value
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtBKPF-BKTXT").Text = Cells(i, 1).Value
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRF05V-NEWKO").Text = Cells(i, 3).Value
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRF05V-NEWKO").SetFocus
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRF05V-NEWKO").caretPosition = 10
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        
        Cells(i, 5).Value = "OK"
       

End If
   i = i + 1
Loop
```